# MySQL SELECT two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables:

Table_1:

```
 | ID     | numero | apagado
 |  1     |  23    |   0
 |  2     |  56    |   0
 |  3     |  156   |   0
 |  4     |  48    |   0
```

Table_2:

```
 | ID_Table_1 | data_inspecao |
 |  1         |  2014-01-03   |
 |  2         |  2014-01-08   |
 |  1         |  2014-02-20   |
 |  4         |  2014-01-06   |
 |  2         |  2014-01-23   |
```

I want to get the most recent 'data_inspecao' for all the 'numero'.

In my example I want the following result:

```
 | ID_Table_1 | data_inspecao |
 |  1         |  2014-02-20   |
 |  2         |  2014-01-23   |
 |  4         |  2014-01-06   |
```

I have the following SELECT statement, but if I change 'DESC' for 'ASC' the result is the same, I did not get the most recent 'data_inspecao':

```
SELECT 
    e.numero, i.data_inspecao 
FROM 
    table_1 e 
INNER JOIN 
    table_2 i ON i.ID_Table_1 = e.numero 
WHERE 
    e.numero = 6 AND e.apagado = 0 
GROUP BY 
    e.numero 
ORDER BY 
    i.data_inspecao DESC
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: use max over data_inspectao and group by the other ungroupped columns

Comment: make sure the `data_inspecao` field has the type `date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using your example with added `MAX` aggregation

```
SELECT 
    e.numero, Max(i.data_inspecao) as MostRecentDate 
FROM 
    table_1 e 
INNER JOIN 
    table_2 i ON i.ID_Table_1 = e.numero 
GROUP BY 
    e.numero 
ORDER BY 
   e.numero
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.ID_Table_1, MAX(i.data_inspecao )
FROM table_1 e 
INNER JOIN table_2 i ON i.ID_Table_1 = e.ID     
GROUP BY i.ID_Table_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that you wanted the most recent `data_inspecao` for all the `numero`. But in your example of "I want the following result", it seems you want the most recent `data_inspecao` for the `ID_table_1`. These two would require very different queries. I would try to clarify this before I write my query.

If you want to get the most recent `data_inspecao` for all the `numero`, I would try the answer by user @Milen Pavlov.

But if you really meant to get the result like your example result table, I would try this query instead:

```
SELECT ID_TABLE_1, MAX(data_inspecao)
FROM Table_2
GROUP BY ID_TABLE_1;
```